# Order properties of a Class in specific way in List Of Objects

Tags: c#

I am using C# .Net Core.

I have a situation where I need to keep object property in certain order in a collection List(Type T).
Pay attention to my DTO class below, it has LastName, then FirstName and so on.
This is NOT in Alphabetical order. But C# List is producing each object in collection that has property in Alphabetical order.

```
public class SearchResultPersonDto 
{
 public string LastName { get; set; }
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string BirthDate { get; set; }
 public string SSN { get; set; }
 public string City { get; set; }
 public string State { get; set; }
 public string Salary{ get; set; }
 public string Position { get; set; }
 public string TaxYear { get; set; }
 public string IncomeBracket { get; set; }
}
```

I have an API method which builds collection of matching search result
`List<SearchResultPersonDto> finalResult = new List<SearchResultPersonDto>();`

The problem is, each object in List orders it's property in Alphabetical order. Pay attention to above DTO class, it has LastName, then FirstName and so on. DTO has property which is NOT in  alphabetical order. On the top of that I also need to be able to re-order the property in specific way e.g. TaxYear, Position, IncomeBracket and so on.

I have UI that consume API as JSON, and it shows the each property as column of data grid in the order as I see on object collection. I don't have option to change on UI.

Comment: *"C# List always orders object items which has Properties in Alphabetical order"* - Where are you seeing them in any kind of order besides the declared order in your source code? If you're looking at it in the debugger, that's the debugger doing that, not C# or the `List<T>` class.

Comment: If you're talking about the order they appear in JSON, that's probably reflection order, which is usually declared order but not guaranteed to be that. You can't control the order of JSON properties unless you write your own converter for the type, and it's worth noting that the order is not important to a conforming parser.

Comment: *"Now the problem is, C# List always orders object items which has Properties in Alphabetical order."* Aside from this being incorrect, you haven't described *why* it's a problem. Please update your question with the goal you're trying to accomplish. 
Property "ordering" is only relevant to UI (as far as I know), and can be controlled by you when you show data to the user. The actual order in which properties are defined in the object itself is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you talking about some kind of serialization? Do you have a [mre]?

Comment: This has nothing to do with a list. You'll see it for a single object if you look at the properties in the same way.

Comment: Hi madreflection
I am seeing property is in Alphabetical order that when I use Debugger View (Magnifying glass). Issue is also reflect on UI where UI takes whatever order I send out as JSON. I tried  something like adding Tag to each property in the Class to keep in order [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]. This did not meet my goal either.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6MlVER), using either Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json. Please [edit] your post with a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

if you use System.Text.Json,can use attribute [JsonPropertyOrder(Number)] for sorting but It doesn't matter if you debug

```
public class SearchResultPersonDto
{
    [JsonPropertyOrder(1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyOrder(2)]

    public string FirstName { get; set; }



    [JsonPropertyOrder(3)]
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyOrder(4)]
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyOrder(5)]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyOrder(6)]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyOrder(7)]
    public string Salary { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyOrder(8)]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyOrder(9)]
    public string TaxYear { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyOrder(10)]
    public string IncomeBracket { get; set; }
}
```

Description  JsonPropertyOrder:

It's supported in .Net 6 and greater using JsonPropertyOrderAttribute:

- Specifies the property order that is present in the JSON when
  serializing. Lower values are serialized first. If the attribute is
  not specified, the default value is 0.

  If multiple properties have the same value, the ordering is undefined
  between them.

The reason for using JsonPropertyOrder

1.if you use [JsonPropertyOrder(-number)] with negative numbers, at first serialized properties with this numbers, after properties without attribute numbers.

2.
In the case of a derived class from a base class you can't define them in the order you want them in

example code to Serialize

```
using System.Text.Json;

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new SearchResultPersonDto()
{
    LastName = "s",
    FirstName = "dfd",
    BirthDate = "555",
    City="c",
    IncomeBracket="c",
    Position="ad",
    Salary="sss",
    SSN="ss",
    State="ss",
    TaxYear="adsad"
}, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true });
```

Result:

```
{
  "LastName": "s",
  "FirstName": "dfd",
  "BirthDate": "555",
  "SSN": "ss",
  "City": "c",
  "State": "ss",
  "Salary": "sss",
  "Position": "ad",
  "TaxYear": "adsad",
  "IncomeBracket": "c"
}
```

Comment: Your code works exactly the same without the JsonPropertyOrder attribute. https://dotnetfiddle.net/CAC4VF The OP has also indicated they tried using this attribute.

Comment: i said,you change soring with JsonPropertyOrder"can use attribute [JsonPropertyOrder(Number)] for sorting"

Comment: Please explain why it's necessary to use this attribute if the output is the same without the attribute.

Comment: 1.Use inherited (please see this is https://makolyte.com/system-text-json-control-the-order-that-properties-get-serialized/) 2.add a filed ,you doesn't want to change sorting filed(you can  sorting with this atturibute,example   [JsonPropertyOrder(-1000)]  public string Data { get; set; }: Data can be first  )

Comment: if you use [JsonPropertyOrder(-number)] with negative numbers, at first serialized properties with this numbers, after properties without attribute numbers.